# A way to combine a vertex shape with a pose?

Tags: rigging, armature, bones, weight-painting, shape-keys

I have been doing some rigging recently on a character I made, I was trying to make the fist pose and found out that the only way to having a realistic fist pose is by moving some mesh vertices around while keeping the bones at the fist pose (bone deformation almost gave me a heart attack)  is there a way to retrieve the fist pose from the pose library along with the shape key of the adjusted vertices automatically so they form a total fist shape? I dont think drivers will be of help for me, cause this involves many finger bones and the shot is not worthy of this setup.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

**Per hand Driver Approach**,

Add a custom property (for example sake "prop") to the hand bones (assuming names "hand.L" and "hand.R") of your armature.  Use this property to drive your fist shape-keys.

Hunt down the hand bone as the variable target, make it a single property variable type,  with `pose.bones["hand.R"]["prop"]` the data_path.

[image]

Each bone custom property is saved with the pose.

Comment: Perfect, I guess shape keys is the only solution for this, having it switched on and off with a custom property in the hand bones is the most efficient in my case, thanks alot.